# Find min in list - python

Tags: python, class

I'm doing a kind of Dijkstra as homework.
This is how the class `Vertex` looks.

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.minDistance = float('inf')
        self.previousVertex = None
```

In other class I have a list of `unvisited vertexes` and I want to find a minimum distance, so I can recursively work with the `Vertex` having that `minDistance`.

e.g. `unvisited = [Vertex1, Vertex2,...]`

Tried to do it with `for` cycle, but by iterating it and saving it to a variable didn't work as it saved only the last value.
How can I find a min value of a class atribute in list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more Pythonic one-liner:

`minDistance = min(otherVertex.distance for otherVertex in unvisited)`

Comment: As a complement to this, you can find the `Vertex` which has the minimum distance with `minVertex = min(unvisited, key=operator.attrgetter('distance'))`

Comment: Díky, co když mi to ale najde nekonečno jako minimum?

Comment: @AlessandroPetric: Please try to [stick to English on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/322040).

Comment: Sorry, @ShadowRanger saw that the guy who answered is from Czech Republic, so I wrote it in czech. Anyway, it's working.

Comment: You have to take care about `inf` yourself - that depends on your application. In Dijkstra it could mean there are no adjacent vertices = abort search.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, but your solution does not work when you e.g. need to call a method of the `Vertex` with `self` to calculate the distance, so I wanted to show the more general and "clear-cut" solution.